# How to shift or choose left side calendar in react-date-range control

Tags: reactjs, react-date-range

How to shift or choose the left side of the calendar as it doesn't look good in the scenario where mindate is yesterday to block previous dates and today's date is on right side of control with all the previous dates blocked.

This doesn't look good
[image: This doesn't look good]

This is required
[image: This is needed]